# Trying to read an entire file but getting [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, directory, operating-system

I have looked trough many questions regarding this problem, but none seemed to solve my question.

I am currently learning Python and was testing out reading from a file.
When I tried to read an entire file like this:

```
with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
print(contents)
```

Even though I have saved a file called 'pi_digits.txt' in the same directory, an error message pops up, saying:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pi_digits.txt'`

The pi_digits.txt file is just a file containing the the first 12 digits of pi.
Now my question is: Why does it output an error stating, that pi_digit.txt does not exist?

Comment: How are you running Python? Odds are, the current working directory is not the same as the script directory (it's only going to look for `pi_digits.txt` in the working directory). Solution is to read from a script relative path, e.g. using `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'pi_digits.txt')` instead of `'pi_digits.txt'`.

Comment: _Why does it output an error stating, that pi_digit.txt does not exist?_ Because that file does not exist **in the current directory**.

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger, your answer worked out!

Comment: Always be mindful that unless you are explicitly providing the *absolute* path, the file/path you provided will always be considered by Python interpreter as *relative* to your current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend adding the following lines before the call to `open`, to see if the current directory is where you think it is:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

My guess is that statement will print something that you didn't expect (e.g., a directory that doesn't contain a file called *pi_digits.txt*).  If not, then please post the command line you used to call your script, the directory from which the command is run, and we can try to assist further.

Comment: In addition to this, in Windows when I first learning to program, since Windows hides file extensions by default I accidentally named my input file `file.txt.txt` instead of `file.txt`

Comment: @merkman Yeah, disabling that "feature" is the first thing I always do on first login to a Windows machine.  Equally annoying is Chrome hiding the protocol in URLs.